# Is there a way to convert PubSubIO read to UnboundedSource source

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to use `PubSub subscription` as a bounded source to minimise cost of streaming pipeline running all the time.Similar question was asked before [Batch Pipeline with Unbounded Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807808/apache-beam-batch-pipeline-with-unbounded-source?rq=1) but no solution. I came across this answer [What PipelineRunners](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/93) which says we can turn the `UnboundedSource` into a `BoundedSource` for testing using `withMaxNumRecords`.Is it possible to use PubSubIO as input here or Is there a way to convert `PubSubIO` read to `unboundedSource`?

```java
UnboundedSource<String> unboundedSource  = .; // How to Use PubSub here?
PCollection<String> boundedPubsubCollection =
    p.apply(Read.from(unboundedSource).withMaxNumRecords(10));
```

Comment: Did you try to read into pubsub as unbounded source, with your maxNumRecord and with the stream param to false ?

Comment: Yes I tried it seems - `UnboundedSource unboundedSource=PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic("testTopic"); `is illegal. Anyway to use this?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's illegal, it's a PCollection which is returned. Anyway, what do you want to achieve? What's your requirement? What's your target? By thinking to your solution, I think that dataflow isn't the right platform (I don't talk about Beam programming language, but only the platform where you run your pipeline.) Can you edit your question with a wider vision of your target?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere My question is very much similar to [Batch Pipeline with Unbounded Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807808/apache-beam-batch-pipeline-with-unbounded-source?rq=1).Its like convert steam to Batch pipeline. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not well supported by PubSubIO, and it's a little odd for 'the Beam model'. Some options:

1. Have you tried starting your pipeline, and periodically draining it?
2. If that doesn't work, you should post a feature request in the Beam mailing list or [issue tracker](https://jira.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/).