# Google Dataflow Pricing Streaming Mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, iot, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to Dataflow.
I'd like to use the Dataflow streaming template "Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery" to transfer some messages, say 10000 per day.
My question is about pricing since I don't understand how they're computed for the streaming mode, with Streaming Engine enabled or not.
I've used the Google Calculator which asks for the following:
Machine Type, Number of worker nodes used by the job, If streaming or Batch job, Number of GB of Persistent Disks (PD), Hours the job runs per month.

Consider the easiest case, since I don't need many resources, i.e.

- Machine type: n1-standard1
- Max Workers: 1
- Job Type: Streaming
- Price: in us-central1

**Case 1: Streaming Engine DISABLED**

- Hours using the vCPU = 730 hours (1 month always active). Is this always true for the streaming mode? Or there can be a case in a streaming mode in which the usage is lower?
- Persistent Disks: 430 GB HDD, which is the default value.

So I will pay:

- (vCPU) 730 x $0.069(cost vCPU/hour) = $50.37
- (PD) 730 x $0.000054 x 430 GB = $16.95
- (RAM) 730 x $0.003557 x 3.75 GB = $9.74
  TOTAL: $77.06, as confirmed by the calculator.

**Case 2 Streaming Engine ENABLED.**

- Hours using the v CPU = 730 hours
- Persistent Disks: 30 GB HDD, which is the default value

So I will pay:

- (vCPU) 30 x $0.069(cost vCPU/hour) = $50.37
- (PD) 30 x $0.000054 x 430 GB = $1.18
- (RAM) 30 x $0.003557 x 3.75 GB = $9.74
  TOTAL: $61.29 PLUS the amount of Data Processed (which is extra with Streaming Engine)

Considering messages of 1024 Byte, we have a traffic of 1024 x 10000 x 30 Bytes = 0.307 GB, and an extra cost of 0.307 GB x $0.018 = $0.005 (almost zero).

Actually, with this kind of traffic, I will save about $15 in using Streaming Engine.
Am I correct? Is there something else to consider or something wrong with my assumptions and my calculations?
Additionally, considering the low amount of data, is Dataflow really fitted for this kind of use? Or should I approach this problem in a different way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not false, but not perfectly accurate.

In the streaming mode, your Dataflow always listen the PubSub subscription and thus you need to but up full time.

In batch processing, you normally start the batch, it performs its job and then it stops.

In your comparison, you consider to have a batch job that runs full time. It's not impossible, but it doesn't fit your use case, I think.

---

About streaming and batching, all depends on your need of real time.

- If you want to ingest the data in BigQuery with low latency (in few seconds) to have real time data, streaming is the good choice
- If having data only updated every hour or every day, batch is a more suitable solution.

---

A latest remark, if your task is only to get message from PubSub and to stream write to BigQuery, you can consider to code it yourselves on Cloud Run or Cloud Functions. With only 10k messages per day, it will be free!

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply, it gave me a great hint on a different implementation using Cloud Functions.
However, coming back to Dataflow, the option Streaming Engine I was referring to, is inside the streaming mode, I wasn't thinking about batch mode.  
Take a look at (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine).
The batch mode is probably more adapt for my use-case, but I was looking for a templated solution, and the only templates which import from Pub/Sub are those in Streaming mode. Let me know!

Comment: Yes the current template is only in streaming. But you can write your own by starting from the [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) if you want to deactivate the streaming or customize it.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere,
I tried the Cloud Function possibility. It works and it is perfectly fitted for me.
However I want to compare it with a Batch solution in Dataflow, editing the PubSubToBigQuery.java template.
I still have the problem cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815045/is-there-a-way-to-convert-pubsubio-read-to-unboundedsource-source)
The read FromSubscription method return a PCollection, but I need an UnboundedSource. for then converting it into BoundedSource and apply the pipeline to a finite number of data.
Can you give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Previously (years ago) it was possible to set the streaming parameter to false and to use PubSub in batch. I tested again tonight, and it's no longer possible :(